# Proxy in AWS to catch specific messages and reply?

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, transparentproxy

**Problem:**
our system, running on AWS, uses an external service and we need to test specific flows/APIs of it. There is no way to completely mock this external service.

**Desired solution:**
we need an entity on the network which would monitor, catch specific messages from internal services and reply back in the name of the external service. I don't know if this is feasible at all. What i've found so far is that we probably need a transparent proxy. Maybe Squid...

**Question:**
can you recommend a solution(framework, tool, etc) that could do the above described tasks? If you can give details how to implement that would be great too.